# Google appengine project Third party library import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am developing an app-engine project in Google App Engine Standard Environment Python 2.7.
Mainly my application using webapp2 for request handling(WSGI protocol) and jinja2 as the python frame work.

I am getting no module name error when try to import google-cloud-bigquery, google-auth, google-oauth2.

These are the solutions i have tried so far to fix but could not success anyone of them.

Here's the previous [question]: [Google Cloud BigQuery Import not working in app engine project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418201/google-cloud-bigquery-import-not-working-in-app-engine-project)

Second one [question]: [Error importing Google Cloud Bigquery api module in python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886217/error-importing-google-cloud-bigquery-api-module-in-python-app)

Google document [a link]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: webapp2
 version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /fav_icon
  static_dir: fav_icon

- url: /fav_icons
  static_dir: fav_icons

- url: /css
  static_dir: css
  mime_type: 'text/css'

 - url: /js
   static_dir: js

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

**main.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
import csv
from jinja2 import Template
import flask
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth
from google.oauth2 import service_account
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
# TODO: to add other directories here that contains the templates.
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
autoescape=True)

class Bigquery(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     """docstring for ."""
     def get(self):
         ser_acc_file_path = os.getcwd()+ str('/file_name.json')
         credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(ser_acc_file_path)
         if credentials.requires_scopes:
           credentials =credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'])
          bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='project_123', credentials=credentials)
          query_results = bigquery_client.run_sync_query("""SELECT * FROM `project_123.dataset.table` LIMIT 100;""")
          query_results.use_legacy_sql = False
          query_results.run()
          rows = query_results.fetch_data()
          self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
          self.response.write(str(row))
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=[
('/',Bigquery))],debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

All the third party libraries are installed in lib directory using pip.

Comment: what does your `lib` folder structure look like.

Comment: project-folder-->lib(dir) and the app.yaml, requirement.txt, appengine_config.py files are in the same project-folder

Comment: What I think @Alex was asking is does your project have the following: `lib/google/cloud/bigquery.py`, `lib/google/auth.py`, and `lib/google.oauth2.service_account.py` (or whatever files you expect the imports to pull from)

Comment: @Brendan Goggin In my lib folder contains google directory, which has some 'auth, cloud, logging. etc.. ' directories. not the modules that you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611347/django-adding-library-in-my-lib-folder/45613569#45613569). [Here is a link to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) for using third-party libs in GAE. Basically, the solution is you make a new file called `appengine_config.py` in the same directory as your `app.yaml`, and that file should look like this:

```
# appengine_config.py
import os
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

Also, I don't know if this is causing problems at the moment, but you should remove the the last two lines of your `main.py`, the ones that look like `if __name__ == __main__`. When you run your app either with `dev_appserver.py` or by deploying it to GAE, it will establish the wsgi app for you, set up the handlers according to `app.yaml` and your Routes, etc. It should not be using `app.py` as your main module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is worked now after updating the requirement.txt file with all packages, and now I am facing issues with deployment. any one knows how to deploy the application contains third party library.

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/` should place the packages into the `lib/` directory, and then `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` will deploy your app including the `lib/` directory which contains the third-party libraries.

Comment: After deployment, it's getting a server error. shows 500 as HTTP status. This is the response Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: The `deploy` command is giving the error, or the server is giving errors when you make requests to it? In either case, please give more information on the error. An HTTP 500 error could be caused by just about anything.

Comment: actually, it is causing due to _ctype import error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515151/cant-import-the-ctypes-python-library-in-google-app-engine this same error I am getting.