# devappserver.py for app engine std on localhost is clearing os.uname & crashing in ctypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have foolishly reinstalled all my Python 2.7 dependencies and it's broken something.  If you notice on line 1, os.uname() has a valid value, but by the time GAE calls ctypes module (line 3), it has been emptied and my local server won't respond to the client.

This feels a bit over my head & I'd appreciate any guidance.

```
os.uname() is: 19.3.0
INFO     2020-03-04 19:11:42,584 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 8624
os.uname() is: 
ERROR    2020-03-04 19:11:43,311 wsgi.py:269] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/service_backend/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import endpoints as google_cloud_endpoints
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/endpoints/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .api_config import api, method
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/endpoints/api_config.py", line 44, in <module>
    import attr
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/attr/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import converters, exceptions, filters, validators
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/attr/filters.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._compat import isclass
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/attr/_compat.py", line 139, in <module>
    set_closure_cell = make_set_closure_cell()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/attr/_compat.py", line 129, in make_set_closure_cell
    ctypes = import_ctypes()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/site-packages/attr/_compat.py", line 95, in import_ctypes
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    if int(_os.uname()[2].split('.')[0]) < 8:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: I should also mention that the python interpreter running above is one installed by Homebrew (not sure how it got linked to GCP) but that's different than the interpreter in my venv in which all my tests are passing.  But I don't know how to make devappserver use a different interpreter or if that will even solve this problem.

Comment: I don't really know what your issue is, but `os.uname()` can't be "cleared". It's a wrapper around the POSIX system call [uname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/uname.html).

Comment: My print above (line 3) clearly show's it as empty.  My guess is that devappserver is emulating the GAE environment & that call returns an empty string in that case.   I have no knowledge of any of this, but I see what I see so I'm making some guesses.

Comment: why are you putting the os.uname inside an int() function ? seems to me the issue is there.

Comment: @Waelmas  that is NOT our code ... it's happening inside the BUILT-IN cytypes libarary:   Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs` hasn't been using ctypes [since 19.2.0](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/pull/522), so the solution is to get your dependencies somehow updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the stubs file located within the devappserver2/python/runtime.

`google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/stubs.py`

From:

```
    def fake_uname(): 
      """Fake version of os.uname.""" 
      return ('Linux', '', '', '', '')
```

To:

```
    def fake_uname():
      """Fake version of os.uname."""
      return ('Linux', 'local', '19', 'Darwin Kernel Version 19', 'x86_64')
```

It isn’t a great long term solution because updates to the gcloud tool chain will likely wipe out the changes.