# dev_appserver.py is causing error while running python 2.7 project locally but working fine on GAE

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

Running  dev_appserver.py  is causing the error for Python 2.7 (Flask 1.1.1) project locally.

```
 File "/Users/honeythakuria/Work/project/lib/pathlib2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import ctypes
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", 
  line
 29, in <module>
if int(_os.uname()[2].split('.')[0]) < 8:
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Same project is running fine on GAE with pycrypto libraries in .yaml

Can someone help in running the project locally ?

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with the 'ctypes' version. Could you run a pip freeze on GAE and in your local machine? Is the 'ctypes' library installed in your local machine? Does the 'ctypes' library version match in both cases?

Comment: It is the part of the library itself.
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py
And yes, same version on GAE and in local

Comment: Run the pip freeze command as shown in the link. A list of the installed packages will be shown. Compare the outputs from both, your local and the App Engine's one http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/pip-freeze-Python.php

Comment: It's the same. pip3 freeze is giving the same output. Also, I've cloned the same branch which is deployed on GAE.

Comment: Have you checked this threads? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533259/devappserver-py-for-app-engine-std-on-localhost-is-clearing-os-uname-crashing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698071/ctypes-init-fails-using-local-app-engine-django-and-virtualenv-with-python-2-7